# Angular "master" check-all checkbox which sets checked status of all other checkboxes

Tags: angularjs

I would like to do this:

```
       [ ]  all toppings
       -----------------
       [ ] mushrooms
       [ ] peppers
       [ ] extra cheese
       [ ] artichokes
```

When the user checks or unchecks [  ] all toppings, the individual toppings are set either all checked or all unchecked.

The individual checkboxes are working properly. But when the controller iterates the toppings list in the `setAll()` method, setting the selected state of each, the UI does not show the change.

```
$scope.items = [{id: 100, name: "mushrooms", price: 1.00}, ....]

<div>
    <p><input type="checkbox" id="allToppings" 
              data-ng-click="setAll($event)"> all
            </p>
            <hr/>
            <p data-ng-repeat="item in items">
              <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="item.selected" 
                  data-ng-click="item.selected=!item.selected">  {{item.name}}
            </p>
   </div>



 $scope.setAll = function (e) {    
       for (item in items) {
         item.selected = (e.target.checked);
      }                       
 }
```

The `setAll()` method is invoked, and each item's selected property is set correctly.  What is the proper way to have the UI show the changes?  Does toppings array need to be `watched`?

Comment: shouldn't use `for in` on arrays

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When iterating through an array like `for (item in items)`, `item` will be the index of each item. Try this:

```
for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
    items[i].selected = (e.target.checked);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for pointing out the error.  I can accept your answer in 8 minutes :-)

Answer (score 0):

You might want to use the framework's very own [angular.forEach](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.forEach)

```
$scope.setAll = function (e) {
    angular.forEach(items, function(item, key) {
        item.selected = e.target.checked;
    });
}
```